# WPF - Bug allowing multiple selection in a radiobutton group

Tags: wpf, mvvm, radio-button

I have multiple ratio buttons in itemscontrols and datatemplates binded to database data in a MVVM / prism application. Each group of radio buttons is grouped with a name accordingly so that they are seprate groups.

The problem I'm having (and goes against convention of radio buttons) is that you can select multiple options within the group. Not all options allow multiple selection. Some behave as they should others do not. On inspection through snoop all radio buttons are part of the same group but with multiple buttons reporting true to IsChecked.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT - Code

XAML

```
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,10">
                                        <TextBlock Margin="5,5,0,5"
                                                   FontSize="16"
                                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                                   Foreground="{Binding      Path=ThemeBackground}"
                                                   Text="From" />
                                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InternetItems}">
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <RadioButton Margin="5"
                                                                 Content="{Binding Path=Title}"
                                                                 GroupName="InternetFrom"
                                                                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                                                                 IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl>
                                    </StackPanel>
```

View Model

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> InternetItems
    {
        get
        {
            return
                new ObservableCollection<Item>(
                    _items.Where(x => x.Category == Category.InternetFrom).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder));
        }

    }
```

Edit -

Problem resolved. Code behind was initiating a new observable collection each time a radio button was selected leading to multiple datacontexts regardless of the groupnames of the radio buttons being the same

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML.

Answer (score 3):

`RadioButton` controls are mutually excusive if they share the same container (e.g. anything derives from `Panel`, or `ContentControl`). In your case, each item generated in your `ItemsControl` is a separate container thus the buttons are not automatically mutually exclusive.

For example:
If your `ItemsControl` is setup like this, the buttons are mutually exclusive:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <RadioButton Content="1" />
    <RadioButton Content="2" />
    <RadioButton Content="3" />
    <RadioButton Content="4" />
</ItemsControl>
```

But this is not:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Content="1" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Content="2" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Content="3" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Content="4" />
    </Grid>
</ItemsControl>
```

As Dean said, assigning the same `GroupName` property will solve your problem.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Content="1"
                        GroupName="Group1" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Content="2"
                        GroupName="Group1" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Content="3"
                        GroupName="Group1" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton Content="4"
                        GroupName="Group1" />
    </Grid>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Edit**

If you have multiple `ItemsControl`s, you can simply set a different `GroupName` for `RadioButton`s in each `ItemsControl`. An in-scope default style comes in handy in this case:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Setter Property="GroupName"
                        Value="Group1" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Content="1" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Content="2" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Content="3" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Content="4" />
        </Grid>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Setter Property="GroupName"
                        Value="Group2" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Content="1" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Content="2" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Content="3" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Content="4" />
        </Grid>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something wrong, `RadioButton`s within a same group are mutually exclusive. If you use `GroupName` Property to assign two or more `RadioButton`s to a group you will be able to select only one `RadioButton` from that group.

[RadioButton.GroupName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets the name that specifies which RadioButton controls are
>   mutually exclusive.
>
> The user can choose one RadioButton in each group.

Do you really think you discovered such a fundamental bug in the .NET Framework that no one reported yet and was not fixed already?

Comment: I think it would be the sort of thing some one would have noticed long before me. But I have multiple Itemcontrols (different groupnames) on the same page and I've read alot of problems with people being only able to select one across multiple groups on in the same view. I'm wondering is it possible an style could be setting and allowing this some how?

Sorry no code. I'm at home it's at work ...

Comment: @user3195554 whatever your problem is, I'm pretty sure it's a problem with `your` code, rather than WPF. I have implemented TONs of RadioButton-based UIs and NEVER faced any problem.

Comment: @user3195554 You callede it "WPF Bug" so I'm not sure that statement is accurate...

Comment: My apologies I meant "WPF - bug..."

Comment: Adding it as a recourse to the itemscontrol lead to being able to select every radio button

Comment: Problem resolved. Code behind was initiating a new observable collection each time a radio button was selected leading to multiple datacontexts regardless of the groupnames of the radio buttons being the same